# Multiple undefined reference to libyuv variables

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm having issue with libyuv
I'm trying to compile some code i found [here](https://github.com/letmaik/pyvirtualcam/blob/master/pyvirtualcam/native_shared/image_formats.h) with some of my code.
In order to do so, i use this CMakelist.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project( test )
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable( app src/main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( app ${OpenCV_LIBS} uv)
```

But unfortunately, i'm having a lot of :

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/capture.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `gray_to_bgra(unsigned char const*, unsigned char*, int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x738): undefined reference to `J400ToARGB'
```

and this for all value presents in image_formats.h.
I really don't understand why these error show up.

I also tried to compile using `g++ -std=c++17 src/main.cpp  -I /usr/local/include/opencv4 -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -luv` but same thing happen.

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks by advance

Comment: Where is the function `J400ToARGB` defined? Are you including the proper source file or library?

Comment: J400ToARGB is present a line 14 from [this file](https://github.com/letmaik/pyvirtualcam/blob/master/pyvirtualcam/native_shared/image_formats.h)

and `#include <libyuv.h>` is present in the file

Comment: Standard `libuv` library provides `uv.h` header: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libuv0.10-dev/filelist. It seems that header `libyuv.h` is provided by **some other library**. Note also onto `y` in the name of the header: it doesn't correspond to `uv.h` or `libuv.h`.

Comment: So you just extracted some code from the project `pyvirtualcam` and failed to compile it, the reason seems that you have missed copying some utils functions.

Comment: `libyuv.h` is from the [libyuv project](https://chromium.googlesource.com/libyuv/libyuv/+/refs/heads/main/include/libyuv.h), not libuv. I'm going to edit this question to remove the [libuv] tag since it appears the reference to libuv is due to confusing libuv with libyuv